# STM32CubeIDE unable to connect to STM32f103c6t6 board, first upload was successful, but after several uploads i got this issue

Tags: arm, stm32, microcontroller

Error in final launch sequence:

Failed to execute MI command:
target extended-remote localhost:3333

Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:3333: The system tried to join a drive to a directory on a joined drive.
Failed to execute MI command:
target extended-remote localhost:3333

Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:3333: The system tried to join a drive to a directory on a joined drive.
localhost:3333: The system tried to join a drive to a directory on a joined drive.

I uploaded the code first time and it was successful, now after several uploads this issue popped up, although I didn't unplug the device.

Comment: was this a blue pill?  your new firmware didnt have the usb code needed?  you used usb to program it?   that device does not have a usb bootloader.  if you are using the uart as an interface then it is a boot0/1 pin thing then.  and you would just use a programmer tool (or write your own it is trivial, at times as easy or easier than trying to get some third party tool to work) not a debugger.  unless you put it in your firmware you have nothing for the debugger to talk to.  Unless you are using swd which is yet another option.  provide more info.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: when I have exactly the same error, which pops up randomly without any special reason once every 20 uploads, I have to replug the USB and it works (the CubeIDE says "reconnect USB" after identical error text). I have no idea what exactly the error means and why it appears at absolutely random moments during upload tho. Make sure BOOT0/BOOT1 pins are in correct states.